# Can I rely on React state being updated in a form onSubmit handle?

Tags: reactjs

React state updates are asynchronous, so you shouldn't do [things like this](https://underbelly.is/writing-about/mastering-asynchronous-state-setters-in-functional-components):

```
const _handleChange = (event) => {
  setEmail(event.target.value);
  _updateEmailPermissions(email);
};
```

Because the setter might not actually finish before the update function is called.

But what if we have something like this?

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    _updateEmailPermissions(email);
    // ...
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <SomeComponent onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
)
```

Is this considered safe? I haven't managed to break it no matter how fast I try to jump from changing SomeComponent to submitting the form, but I wonder if there's any case in which the `handleSubmit` function will work with an outdated email.

If it's not safe, what's a better way of doing this considering I need `email` to be usable in the form submit event? Let's assume that updating permissions is quite slow, so I'd rather not use the `useEffect` fix that triggers when `email` is changed to call it.

**Background**

My particular use case is a bit more complex, but I think it reduces to the above example: I actually have a table (AG Grid) in a child component that calls a `setRows` React state setter passed as a prop to it whenever a row changes. This is fine for me because I will only ever have a few rows. The parent component then uses `rows` in a form submit event like above. I need to know if the `rows` it uses are always the ones actually displayed by the table or if the asynchronous nature of state setters might ever let things get out of sync between row change and form submission.

Comment: for the first scenario, you could have a useEffect which listens to when the email has changed. Then invoke _updateEmailPermissions

Comment: @SteveTomlin yes, but I only really need to update them on submit. What if updating the permissions is quite slow?

Comment: I suggest using this value `event.target.value` instead of `email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.

The update happens asynchronously, but it is still very quick. In the code example below, we are literally trying to use `email` one line of code after calling `setEmail`. Since `setEmail` is asynchronous, this is not a great idea:

```
const _handleChange = (event) => {
  setEmail(event.target.value);
  _updateEmailPermissions(email);
};
```

Although `setState` is asynchronous, in most use cases it will appear to happen instantly.

In your use case, the timeline will always look like `setEmail` -> `user input` -> `_updateEmailPermissions`. In this case, the `user input` step will leave ample time for the `email` state to finish updating.

I've created a code sandbox example showing how quickly `email` state is updated. You can see that the `email` state value which is placed inside a `<p>` is updated very quickly, and is always updated well before the user could possibly click `Submit`. Here's the example: [image: Edit elastic-gagarin-orjie1]

#### Controlled Components

You mentioned that you "need to know if the rows it uses are always the ones actually displayed by the table". You can guarantee this by keep a single source of truth for the data by using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Consider this example:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
...
  return (
        <input
          value={email}
          onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
        />
```

Since we are setting the `value` of our `input` to the state variable `email`, we will always know that whatever value is displayed in the input field is the same as the value stored in the `email` state variable.

If we erroneously omit `value` like this: `<input onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />` then we will have **two** sources of truth: 1. The DOM which handles the html `input` element, and 2. The state variable called `email`. This has potential to cause bugs later.

Comment: Makes sense, I had a feeling I was overthinking things. I'll accept this in a bit if no one else chimes in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this code

```
const _handleChange = (event) => {
let temp =event.target.value;
  setEmail(temp);
  _updateEmailPermissions(temp);
};
```

I think using another event is working safely, but I think you can use a promise for that.

```
setAsyncState = (newState) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => this.setState(newState, resolve))
```

Comment: Yes, that's one of the fixes suggested in the link I gave. But what if updating permissions is slow and I only want to do it on form submit, not on every change?